# Sizing MOSFET VDS to account for Stepper Back EMF

Tags: stepper-motor, motor-controller, physics, back-emf

I'm having difficulty conceptualizing how the Back EMF of a motor, stepper in this case, can damage an H-Bridge MOSFET if the Vds aren't sized correctly. My main issue is my understanding of how the motor's back EMF is generated.

I understand that the Back EMF is proportional to the Speed of the motor. I also know the Back EMF is derived from Lenz Law $$E = -N\frac{d\Phi}{dt}$$ so if the change in flux is positive, the back EMF will be negative and when the change in flux decreases, the Back EMF will be positive.

Suppose I consider a generic H-Bridge setup for each coil, with 4 N-Channel MOSFETS, the appropriate body diodes and a Clamping circuit on the drain of the high-side FETS to protect the power supply. In that case, I can estimate the voltage across my stepper coils to look like this.

[image]

Now if I assume when the current flow from left to right, I can expect to generated a North pole to face toward the rotor, and when the current is flipped, the South pole will face the rotor.
[image]

The points I need help with is what the back EMF looks like at points 2, 3, 4 and 5 of the waveform above.

From the perspective of coil "A" at point 2, the FETs have turned on for coil A and off for coil B  (at some rate of change). The rotor begins to align the south pole teeth with the N pole of the coil A, there will be a large positive change in flux, and therefore the back EMF will oppose the coil voltage.

[image]

At point 3, the S pole of the rotor is completely alighted with the north pole of coil A. There is no change in flux and, therefore, no Back EMF.

[image]

At point 4. The FETs for coil A turn off and turn on for coil B. The Magnetic field for coil A begins to collapse. The voltage across coil A flips, but the current direction and magnetic pole are maintained untill it completely dissipates. As the S pole of the rotor moves away this causes a large negative change in flux, and therefore the Back EMF is positive.

[image]

At point 5, the current in coil A is completely dissipated and sits between the N and S poles of the rotor with no change in flux. There is no current flowing through the coil at this point.

[image]

If the Vds of my FETS were 60V and I had a measure Back EMF of 40Vpp, could I reasonably expect to see damage to my Low side FETS during position 2, since they would have a voltage drop of the ~48V + 20V (Back EMF)

[Edit] Here is what the Clamp Circuit looks like
[image]

Comment: Do you know what the back-emf looks like for a simple solenoid and MOSFET switch with a reverse diode across the solenoid?

Comment: Please show the "clamper circuit". There are very few situations where the supply cannot handle the inductive bEMF from a motor load, and a direct connection between supply and driver is more than adequate.

Comment: @TimWilliams the clamp circuit is essentially a pnp transistor that turns on when the back emf rises above the supply. Seems irrelevant to the original question?

Comment: So, what, a shunt regulator, braking resistor (or, well, transistor)? There is no series diode or anything? The "clamp" being in series suggests it has no shunt capability, hence the question.

Comment: @TimWilliams I added the clamp circuit to the post, its operating as it should.

Comment: Thanks. So about EMF, if the motor is being pushed at some forward speed by the applied voltage (which the EMF opposes, tending to approach in equilibrium, minus load), how would it ever generate more EMF than was put in?

Comment: I think I get what your saying. I think my confusion about the damage and the Vds is more related to the SOA of the FET

Comment: @TimWilliams I think I still may be confused. If you took two identical motors and coupled the shafts together, then ran one motor at some RPM, and measure the generated voltage of the unpowered motor you would see a generated EMF of 100s of volts. 

Would that large voltage not be present in coil B when Coil A is energized?

Comment: Would you, though?